# Unable to determine source of TypeError with ng test

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm running `ng test` in my Angular `7.2.1` project and I'm getting a type error that should be somewhat simple to fix:

`Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. thrown`

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting no stack traces to tell me exactly where this type error is occurring, or in what file. Is there a way to turn on a stack trace so I can get to the bottom of this? I'm running the following command: `ng test --watch=false --source-map=true`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would be helpful to also include the version of `angular-cli` (ng) you are using.

Comment: Yep sorry, 7.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't tell you which unit tests failed? I am assuming the error occurs in the tests that failed.

Maybe you have a setting in `karma.conf.js` that suppresses that stack trace. I am not sure what that setting can be.

Something you can do is change the `reporters` array to remove the `progress` reporter and include the `spec` reporter.

This will show green/red test titles so you can see in which the test the error gets thrown and can pinpoint the component/service/etc.

The reporters array should look like `reporters: ['kjhtml', 'spec']`.

You may have to install `karma-spec-reporter`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter